# Find a row in DataGridView containing the closest matched DateTime object

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I need to search a known column in my `DataGridView` and return the row containing a `DateTime`object with the closest matching time (that is less than the desired search time).

I have used linq in the past to search through a `DataGridView`looking for data.  But in those cases, I was looking for an exact match, as in:

```
public DataGridViewRow FindRow(DataGridView dgv, string columnID, object searchID)
    {
        DataGridViewRow row = dgv.Rows
            .Cast<DataGridViewRow>()
            .Where(r => r.Cells[columnID].Value.Equals(searchID))
            .First();

        return row;
    }
```

Now I have an exact `DateTime`object with a column in my `DataGridView`containing all `DateTime`objects.

```
DateAdded       Data1    Data2
12:34:56.012    x        y
12:34:56.345    x        y
12:34:56.678    x        y
```

In the above case, if I am searching for a `DateTime`object of "12:34:56.4", I want to return the second row containing "12:34:56.345".

I'm still familiarizing myself with linq.  Anytone have any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes asking the questions helps you to answer it yourself...

```
public DataGridViewRow FindRow(DataGridView dgv, DateTime searchID)
    {
        DataGridViewRow row = dgv.Rows
            .Cast<DataGridViewRow>()
            .Where(r => ((DateTime)r.Cells["DateAdded"].Value <= searchID))
            .Last();

        return row;
    }
```

This did the trick.

Comment: Are you guranteed that collection returned by .Where is always going to be in DateAdded order ? If not the Last element might not be the one you want. May want to add an order by to be sure.